# My foundation orbit image slider is working in Codepen but not in Plunker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My Orbit image slider is working as expected in **[Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/labanino/pen/meVBNz)**,

```
<ul class="slider" data-orbit>
  <li>
    <img src="http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/assets/img/examples/satelite-orbit.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="orbit-caption">insert the image caption here</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/assets/img/examples/andromeda-orbit.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="orbit-caption">insert the image caption here</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/assets/img/examples/launch-orbit.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="orbit-caption">insert the image caption here</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and

`$(document).foundation();`

but the very same code is not working in **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4DKYwI4RbmlcUeHDNqXs)**.

So strange. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not referenced your `script.js` in Plunkr.

In Codepen, the JS is added inline with the demo. But in Plunkr, you need to reference the JavaScript file in your HTML code or you can add inline within `<script>$(document).foundation();</script>` before `</body>`

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/js/foundation/foundation.orbit.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script> <!-- Add -->
```

[**Updated Plunkr.co**](http://plnkr.co/edit/F817Gar9bFPk1xiFbhu2?p=preview)

Comment: Lol, too late at night I guess. Thanks.